# Specify a specific repository url in maven settings.xml to deploy in Nexus

Tags: maven, deployment, continuous-integration, nexus

I'm a new guy on Maven and Nexus. 
I have a problem to deploy my maven project (developped with IntelliJ) on my local Nexus.
You will find attached my maven settings.xml

My objective is to deploy my project without modify a pom.xml file, only the ~/.m2/settings.xml

I have tried the following command (which works) : 
$ mvn clean deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=nexus::default::http://192.168.1.8:8081/repository/maven-snapshots

But I want the same results with only :
$ mvn clean deploy

Any idea ?

Thanks

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://192.168.1.8:8081/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
            <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>



    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>


    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>******</password>
        </server>
    </servers>

</settings>
```

Comment: Define the distributionManagement via a property and define the property in your settings.xml ....

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `<properties>` section to your `settings.xml` and add

```
<altDeploymentRepository>nexus::default::http://192.168.1.8:8081/repository/maven-snapshots</altDeploymentRepository>
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem still the same. I add the following to my settings file `<properties> 
  <property>
   <altDeploymentRepository>nexus::default::http://192.168.1.8:8081/repository/maven-snapshots</altDeploymentRepository>
  </property>
 </properties> ` but I have another issue : `[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'properties' (position: START_TAG seen ...</activeProfile>\n\t\t<properties>... @41:15) `

Comment: I also tried : `<property> 
  <altDeploymentRepository>nexus::default::http://192.168.1.8:8081/repository/maven-snapshots</altDeploymentRepository>
 </property>` but there is also a warning with Unrecognised tag: 'property'

Comment: Do this tag need to be in a specific place ?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that the properties lie inside a profile as decribed unter "Properties" in https://maven.apache.org/settings.html